# filterChain.doFilter does not reach its destination in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller that creates a user based on the request body.

```
    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.addNewUser(user);

    }
```

However I have also implemented a filter chain to validate the request's cookie, but since I am creating a user no cookies need to be validated. Therefore I have made the following if statement

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(request.getCookies() == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
....
```

But this is where the issue occurs. It does not reach its end destination (the controller) and create my user. In fact it gives me a 403 Forbidden status code.
What am I missing?

I suspect that my authentication filter might cause the issue. I believe it is trying to authenticate all incoming requests which I don't want for the registration endpoint.

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        
        try {
            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            return authenticate;


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(jwtConfig.getTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
                .signWith(secretKey)
                .compact();


        response.resetBuffer();
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        response.getOutputStream().print(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("Authenticated!"));
        Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", token);
        response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
        response.flushBuffer();

    }
}
```

My configuration

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, secretKey))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig), JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**")
                .hasRole(ApplicationUserRole.USER.name()).anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").allowCredentials(true).allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");


            }
        };
    }
}
```

Just an update:

I have implemented a shouldnotfilter method to avoid filtering on registering, but the problem still persist. I still receive 403 Forbidden but it seems like it does not filter on the registration endpoint

```
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        return "/management/api/v1/users/register".equals(path);
    }
```

Comment: It is not reproducible, add all configuration please.

Comment: @hatefalipoor Added my configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was actually in the configure method. I was actually allowing the specific endpoint to only role-specific users as following:

> .antMatchers("/api/**")             .hasRole(ApplicationUserRole.USER.name()).anyRequest().authenticated()

I missed this, as I was actually using /management/api/ but did not know this was applied and thought there was something wrong with my filter, but it was a security configuration issue.